# Alsamixer S/PDIF Volume [00]

Tags: 16.04, alsa, soundcard, spdif

I am trying to get my digital output to work.
In alsamixer my S/PDIF is on but no frame around and I can't regulate the volume. Is it maby not activated or is my digital input on and output of?

**Specs:**

- Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux Mint)
- Asus Xonar DG (soundcard)

Here are some screenshots of aslamixer and audio manager:

[aslamixer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IojK8.png)

[audio manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxxj7.png)

Would be nice, if someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my scrennshots are correct.
That is the default alsamixer displays spdif.

I did not know, that the optical cable got two diffrent input types. I have changed the direction and did a reboot. All is working now.

Comment: Do SPDIF cables have a preferred direction?